# Code GoogleMap API using Java

Tags: java, json, google-maps

I am trying to automate the tracking of user's location, once he/she connects to our VPN network.

So, I am using geolocation Map API. Passing the Mac address of the router to which user is connected, along with signal strength and channel.

All the object (in JSON format) like

```
{"wifiAccessPoints": [
  {
   "macAddress": "01:23:45:67:89:AB","00:A3:BA:55:12:67:11",
   "signalStrength": 8,
   "channel": 8
  } ]}
```

Send it to "https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=API_KEY"

But, it is showing incorrect location... probably away from expected location.

Please let me know if I am missing somewhere.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are something wrong with your JSON, it should look like this according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/#sample-requests):

```
{
    "wifiAccessPoints": [
        {
            "macAddress": "01:23:45:67:89:AB",
            "signalStrength": 8,
            "channel": 8
        },
        {
            "macAddress": "00:A3:BA:55:12:67:11",
            "signalStrength": 8,
            "channel": 8
        }   
    ]
}
```

and this returns a location of:
[37.42843,-122.07238](https://www.google.com/maps/place/North+Rd,+Mountain+View,+CA+94043/@37.4283636,-122.0735118,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x808fb9f00bbff665:0x6d746177a49cf8d2)

Comment: The longitude and latitude you are getting is correct..? because still I am getting location few meters away from my place. {"wifiAccessPoints":[{"macAddress":"e8:94:f6:69:58:f9"},{"macAddress":"c8:f9:f9:be:df:20"}]}
{
 "location": {
  "lat": 17.4445142,
  "lng": 78.4694999
 },
 "accuracy": 494.0
}

Comment: Yea, it is not real gps so it is never going to be accurate, and that's why you get "accuracy". If you switch to airplane mode and force google maps to use the geolocation, you see a circled area, which basically means you can be in any of these points. http://s17.postimg.org/uj21c1rlr/image.jpg